# What are "nested attributes" in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I'm a newbie in rails.Can anyone tell me what exactly nested attributes are and when to use them, with a good example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will say check these two railscast

1. [Nested Model Form Part 1](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)
2. [Nested Model Form Part 2](http://railscasts.com/episodes/197-nested-model-form-part-2)

   If you want to read check [this](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html#M002132)